# Table <td> pseudo class height (Internet Explorer)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-table, pseudo-element

Firstly, I didn't think this styling would be possible in Chrome/Firefox but surprisingly it worked! However it doesn't display the same in Internet Explorer (What's new huh?).

As it worked in Chrome/Firefox/Safari/Opera I thought it *might* at least work in the latest versions of Internet Explorer but I get the same issue from IE11 down. I've not tested in EDGE yet.

Here's a CodePen showing the mark-up/CSS: http://codepen.io/moy/pen/yewbBx

Basically I have a pretty standard table but a row which is 'selected' is slightly wider than the rest. I achieved this using the `:before` pseudo class for the first and last `<td>` of a selected row, a bit like this:

```
tr.selected td {
    background-color: @brown-lightest;
    position: relative;
}

tr.selected td:first-child:before,
tr.selected td:last-child:before {
    background: @brown-lightest;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: -5px;
    top: 0;
    width: 5px;
}

tr.selected td:last-child:before  {
    left: auto;
    right: -5px;
}
```

Occasionally it 'looks' like it works but it seems like the content of both the first and last `<td>` both need to be the same height for it to work. Even though `td:before {height: 100%;}` is set, it seems to take the height of the text rather than the `<td>`. Which is strange before with it being a table layout all the heights in the row should be the same?

I understand this mightn't be possible in IE but I thought I'd see if anyone had an ideas why this might be happening incase it's something other than the simple fact the browser just can't do it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -3):

Honestly, doing it that way is quite the hassal. I'd recommend checking out Bootstrap CSS, Why? It's designed specifically to combat it.

However if you want to do it like that, just wrap it with a  tag

```
Example
<span style="color: red; background-color: blue; "><td>RandomData</td></span>
```

These are just options however, someone else might be better than I with the first and second child marks.

Comment: I think wrapping `<td>` in `<span>`creates illegal HTML

Comment: I was thinking the same, Other than `<table>` elements, I think any additional tags you need must be within a `<td>` or wrapped around the entire `<table>` element.